# How to enforce stricter method implementation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

To boil down my more complex case, let's have a TS interface like this:

```
interface Foo {
  bar(x: Foo) => void;
}
```

If anyone is implementing or extending this interface, I would like to enforce that the parameter of the `bar` method be of that new type, like this:

```
interface Boo extends Foo {
  bar(x: Boo): void;
}
```

Is it possible to enforce this so there could not be an extension like this:

```
interface Boo extends Foo {
  bar(x: Foo): void;
}
```

I would imagine something like:

```
interface Foo {
  bar(x: Self): void; // x needs to be of the type of the extending interface
}
```

This does not work obviously. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I would probably do something like this. Not sure if this will match your scenario.
`
interface Foo<T> {
  bar: (x: T) => void;
}

export interface Boo extends Foo<Boo> {}`

Comment: Yes, this is also something I was thinking about. I am wondering if there is a nicer way where I do not have to introduce a type parameter which seem a bit arbitrary.

Comment: You can use the [polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to represent what you're calling "`Self`", but it does none of the things you are asking for because of TypeScript's structural type system.  (more...)

Comment: (...continued) You can always extend a function type with a wider parameter; `(x: string | number) => void` is assignable to `(x: string) => void`, so nothing stops someone from extending `Foo` with a `bar` method that accepts all `Foo`s.  That's just how type safety works.  The only thing it prevents is accepting a *narrower* or *unrelated* type, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/N5k62W).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?